# How to Load datepicker with current date plus 30 days

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm creating a project to select the date and load it in an edittext after I select the date the another edit text want to calculate and give the next 30 days of the current selected date example..

i created the first and load sucessfully and i dont know how to load the next 30 days in another Edittext
[image: This is What i Trying To Do/say]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private ImageButton ib;
private Calendar cal;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
private EditText et;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ib.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
} @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog(0);
}
@Override
@Deprecated
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        et.setText(selectedDay + " / " + (selectedMonth + 1) + " / "
                + selectedYear);
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the calender object like this

```
public Calendar getDate(int year, int month, int date) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month); // if Jan is 0
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
    return calendar;
}
```

You can get date, month and year from the calender object

```
public String convertLongToDate(long date) {
    Date convertedDate = new Date(date);
    if (date < 86400000 * 1000L) {
        convertedDate = new Date(date * 1000L);
    }
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    return simpleDateFormat.format(convertedDate);
}
```

call above method as

```
convertLongToDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: I get the date wht i need is when i select any date..the next month of the date(30 or 31 days) want to be load automatically in next editext

Comment: Check the code i am setting the date and adding 30 days to current date. If you pass the date as 09/28/2015 the object splits 10/28/2015.

Comment: you can read the values from calendar object as calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

Comment: ya i got it thanks but i dont know how to load that date in the particular edittext @RAvi

Comment: Thanks But How To Load that calendar date in that particular Edit Text @Ravi